# object.hitTestObject(other_object) is executed too many times

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Why is that happening?

when two objects are touching each other, then i put trace, and they show me many messages:

```
    private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void{

        e.target.x += 4;
        var moved = false
        if(!moved)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < arrows.length; i++)
            {

                if(e.target.hitTestObject(arrows[i]))
                   {

                       trace('boom');
                       moved = true;
                       break;
                   }

            }
        }
```

so here it writes the word "boom" to many times instead of 1 time, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking hit test on every frame, so everytime it gives you the value of hit test. I think your problem is that you define your boolean variable "moved" inside the loop and it loses it's purpose because it's always false when it comes into loop. Try defining your boolean variable outside the function. That will help solve the problem :)

Comment: and also why when the method is executed enterOnFrame, the first object is displayed but he has not contact with other movieClip, but the condition of hitTest return true? why is that?

Comment: Wow i found the answer, is because the current target is hiting it self :)))

Comment: (e.target == arrows[i]) - true

Comment: Sorry I couldn't really understand your question. But I think you're talking about using hitTest to get collision on a Bitmap based object. HitTest method tests collision against both objects' bounding boxes. So you won't be able to get a precise collision using that method. Try using hitTestPoint instead, which takes a Point object as a parameter and tests collision against it.

Comment: Why would you check object's collision against itself?